# How to start a HTML5 video site?

Tags: html5

So... What applications do I need to start a HTML5 based video site? ex.: an educational video site.

Is it technically solvable? A pure HTML5 site? Can anyone post links about it, docs, how to create it? Server must be ex.: a Linux distro.

Comment: It is possible to create a pure HTML5 site, however, you might be restricting your user base to those with the appropriate/latest browsers. You will need to fallback to support other users. Is this really a "Web Applications" question?

Comment: ok, I ~knew that, but how exactly, and with what tools can I make a purely HTML5-based video site? I'm gathering the best tips/etc. :)

Comment: You could perhaps check out [PHPmotion](http://phpmotion.com/), although I'm not sure how HTML5 it is out of the box?